# Blazor WebAssembly was released with token auth for the client side, does anyone know the REST URLs for login, register etc.?

Tags: access-token, blazor, bearer-token, refresh-token, asp.net-blazor

Blazor WebAssembly officially shipped and the project includes token  authentication with identity on the client side.

Does anyone know the  Rest URLS to register, login and get tokens? I'm trying to test with postman but can't seem to track the Rest URLS down for the project.

Comment: That depends on your config. by examining network log on your browser developer tool you'll find them

Comment: An actually there isn't REST enpoints AFAIK

Comment: no endpoints, just a redirect to identity pages with a callback `/Identity/Account/Login` `/Identity/Account/Logout` `/Identity/Account/Manage`  info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-web-app-with-authentication